# Multiple views and UITables from one source, how to populate them?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Okay I have three UITableViews that I need to all originate from the same viewcontroller code. I need to populate them all from the `.m` file of `AG_ViewController`.

**AG_ViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface AG_ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

        IBOutlet UITableView *yesterdayTableView;
        IBOutlet UITableView *tomorrowTableView;
        IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
        IBOutlet UILabel *todaysDate;
        IBOutlet UILabel *subtractDate;
        IBOutlet UILabel *addDate;
    }
    @end
```

**AG_ViewController.m**

```
#import "AG_ViewController.h"
#import "AG_Storage.h"
#import "AG_AddItemViewController.h"

@interface AG_ViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *mainArray;
@property NSMutableArray *yesterdayArray;
@property NSMutableArray *tomorrowArray;
@property NSDate *todayDate;
@property NSDate *tomorrowsDate;
@property NSDate *yesterdaysDate;
@property int counter;

@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *yesterdayButton;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *tomorrowButton;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;

@end

@implementation AG_ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.yesterdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.tomorrowArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self loadInitialData];
}

- (void)loadInitialData
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //NSDate Info

    NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
    NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];

    self.todayDate = today;
    self.tomorrowsDate = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: secondsPerDay];
    self.yesterdaysDate = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -secondsPerDay];

    NSString *todayString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.todayDate];
    NSString *tomorrowString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.tomorrowsDate];
    NSString *yesterdayString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.yesterdaysDate];

    todaysDate.text = todayString;
    addDate.text = tomorrowString;
    subtractDate.text = yesterdayString;

    AG_Storage *theDateToday = [[AG_Storage alloc]init];
    theDateToday.todaysDate = self.todayDate;



    //Populate mainArray
    for (int x= 0; x!=-99; x++) {
        //get ready to call the NSUserDefaults


        NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",todayString,x]];
        AG_Storage *someStorageObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        AG_Storage *storeToArray = [[AG_Storage alloc]init];
        storeToArray.itemName = someStorageObject;


        if (someStorageObject != nil) {
            //add the data to the mainArray and update counter
            [self.mainArray addObject:storeToArray];
            self.counter++;
        }
        else if ((someStorageObject == nil) && (x==99)){
            //exit when done
            x=-100;


        }

    }


    //Populate yesterdayArray
    for (int x= 0; x!=-99; x++) {
        //get ready to call the NSUserDefaults


        NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",yesterdayString,x]];
        AG_Storage *someStorageObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        AG_Storage *storeToArray = [[AG_Storage alloc]init];
        storeToArray.itemName = someStorageObject;


        if (someStorageObject != nil) {
            //add the data to the mainArray and update counter
            [self.yesterdayArray addObject:storeToArray];
            self.counter++;
        }
        else if ((someStorageObject == nil) && (x==99)){
            //exit when done
            x=-100;


        }

    }


    //Populate tomorrowArray
    for (int x= 0; x!=-99; x++) {
        //get ready to call the NSUserDefaults


        NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",tomorrowString,x]];
        AG_Storage *someStorageObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        AG_Storage *storeToArray = [[AG_Storage alloc]init];
        storeToArray.itemName = someStorageObject;


        if (someStorageObject != nil) {
            //add the data to the mainArray and update counter
            [self.tomorrowArray addObject:storeToArray];
            self.counter++;
        }
        else if ((someStorageObject == nil) && (x==99)){
            //exit when done
            x=-100;


        }

    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if(tableView == tomorrowTableView){
        return [self.tomorrowArray count];
    }
    else if(tableView == yesterdayTableView)
        return [self.yesterdayArray count];
    else
        return [self.mainArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewer cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewer dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];
    AG_Storage *toDoItem = [self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;



    if (toDoItem.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;

}



- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];

    AG_AddItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    AG_Storage *item = source.store;

    NSDate *dateCreated = item.creationDate;



    NSString *todayString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.todayDate];
    NSString *dateCreatedString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateCreated];
    NSString *tomorrowString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.tomorrowsDate];
    NSString *yesterdayString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.yesterdaysDate];



    //Set up file storage!



    if (item != nil) {


        if ([dateCreatedString isEqualToString:todayString]) {
            [self.mainArray addObject:item];
            [tableView reloadData];


            NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item.itemName];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",todayString,self.counter]];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


        }
        else if ([dateCreatedString isEqualToString:tomorrowString]){
            [self.tomorrowArray addObject:item];
            [tableView reloadData];

            NSLog(@"THIS WORKED TOO :D");
        }
        else if ([dateCreatedString isEqualToString:yesterdayString]){
            [self.yesterdayArray addObject:item];
            [tableView reloadData];

            NSLog(@"THIS WORKED");
        }
        else{

        }
    }
    self.counter++;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewer didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableViewer deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    AG_Storage *tappedItem = [self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    [tableViewer reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViews commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];

    NSString *todayString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.todayDate];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Delete from storage
        for (int x = 0; x!=-99; x++) {


            NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",todayString,x]];
            AG_Storage *someStorageObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
            AG_Storage *storeToArray = [[AG_Storage alloc]init];
            storeToArray.itemName = someStorageObject;



            AG_Storage *toDoItem = [self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *compare = toDoItem.itemName;

            //If they equal then delete from NSUserDefaults
            if ([compare isEqualToString:someStorageObject]) {

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",todayString,x]];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
                x=-100;
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if (x>10) {
                x=-100;
            }


        }

        [self.mainArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableViews deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];


    }
}

@end
```

I've only ever set up one table at a time, so how do I make `yesterdayTableView` become populated by `yesterdayArray` for instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep one tableView around.

Steps for,One tableView multiple cell as per your need

1) Design seperate cell for yesterday and tomorrow nibs/storyboard

2) swap cell on click of some button `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` via if else conditions.

or else go for viewController containment

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do so,

If you only need to display one tableView at a time you could do something like this in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` data source method:

**The stupid way**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (kAppState_Yesterday) { // Set the controllerstate so that it knows that the arrayDatasource should be yesterday
        // create and return cell corresponding to yesterdayArray.
    }
}
```

If all your cells look the same, you could have a `NSArray *dataSource` and just assign it to the different arrays.

**The "a bit smarter way"**

```
if userClicksButton `display yesterday array`

    self.dataSource = self.yesterdayArray

end
```

In this way, your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be more consistent since if won't be full of conditionals.

If things get more complicated, I would recommend to use Controller Containment.